# bootstrap3 pretty-fullcalendar meteor not reactive in blaze

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I'm using a bootstrap3 pretty-fullcalendar in a project and pre blaze, when I changed some properties of an event (such as color) it was immediately reflected in the display on the calendar. Now, when I change the attribute, I have to reload the calendar manually to have the change show up.

I'm instantiating the calendar in the template render function as

```
Template.packLayout.rendered = function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      //dayClick:function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
      //  Requests.insert({title:'Request',start:date,end:date,color:'red',className:'todo'});
      //  Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
      //},
      eventClick:function(reqEvent,jsEvent,view){
        Session.set('editingReqEvent',reqEvent.id);
        Session.set('showEditEvent',true);
      },
      eventDrop:function(reqEvent){
        Requests.update(reqEvent.id, {$set: {start:reqEvent.start,end:reqEvent.end}});
        Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
      },
      events: function(start, end, callback) {
        var events = [];
        reqEvents = Requests.find();
        reqEvents.forEach(function(evt){
          event = {id:evt._id,title:evt.title,start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:evt.color};
          events.push(event);
        })
        callback(events);
      },
      editable:true,
      weekMode: 'liquid'
    });
}
```

Has something changed that would make this happen?

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be the change to how render works with blaze (only being called once when the template is displayed). This is cool, but I have no idea how to get the events to re-draw when an event changes programmatically (ie, the colour changes etc).

Comment: I think the re-rendering of the calendar used to be driven by this line of code in the template  <input type="hidden" name="lastMod" value="{{lastMod}}" id="lastMod"> If I take the hidden off, I can see the lastMod date changing as expected, but the entire calendar does not re-render.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I've added data: function(){ return findAll(reqEvents)} to the iron router packed template stack. Now, given that the route in now dependent on the cursor returned, and the attribute changes are being written to the database, shouldn't the calendar be re-rendered anyway?

Comment: No joy here, so trying again with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453415/making-bootstrap-calendar-render-when-data-change-in-meteoroy

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i managed to get it working:

1) keep your calendar code as per "rendered"

```
Template.calendar.rendered = function () {
    console.log('Calendar - running redered');
    Session.set('calendarTemplateRendered', true);
    var entries = Calendar.find().fetch(),
        $calendar = $('#calendar');

    $calendar.html('').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        },
        contentHeight: 1100,
        defaultDate: '2014-01-12',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        events: entries
    });
```

Add a autorun:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if (Session.equals('calendarTemplateRendered', false) ||
        !calendarSubs.ready() ||
        typeof Calendar === 'undefined') {
        console.log('exiting because there is no objects to process');
        return;
    }

    console.log('trying to autorun');
    var entries = Calendar.find().fetch(),
       $calendar = $('#calendar');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', entries);
    $calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

Blaze will do the rest for you - (redraw the UI properly). Now you can just modify your Calendar subscription as you like and it will work perfectly.