# Making bootstrap calendar render when data change in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm still struggling to get a calendar to re-render when data changes using meteor blaze. I have put in place an observerChanges function that is firing happily when added, removed or changed are triggered, but I have NO idea how to actually make the calendar update its state.

The handler code is

Meteor.subscribe("reqEvents");

allReqsCursor = Requests.find();

```
var handle = allReqsCursor.observeChanges({
  added: function (id, user) {
    console.log("Request added");
  },
  removed: function () {
    console.log("Request removed");
  },
  changed: function() {
    console.log("Request changed");
//    $('#calendar').fullCalendar().today();
  }
});
```

And the render function itself is

```
Template.packLayout.rendered = function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //dayClick:function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
    //  Requests.insert({title:'Request',start:date,end:date,color:'red',className:'todo'});
    //  Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    //},
    eventClick:function(reqEvent,jsEvent,view){
      Session.set('editingReqEvent',reqEvent.id);
      Session.set('showEditEvent',true);
    },
    eventDrop:function(reqEvent){
      Requests.update(reqEvent.id, {$set: {start:reqEvent.start,end:reqEvent.end}});
      Session.set('lastMod',new Date());
    },
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
      var events = [];
      reqEvents = Requests.find();
      reqEvents.forEach(function(evt){
        event = {id:evt._id,title:evt.title,start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:evt.color};
        events.push(event);
      })
      callback(events);
    },
    editable:true,
    weekMode: 'liquid',
  });
};
```

How do I hook these together? I've tried a few things (as per the commented out code) but it either blows up or renders the calendar twice.

Is this even the best way? Should I put a deps.autorun in somewhere else?? If so where?

Answer (score 1):

FullCalendar should be instantiated only once in Template.packLayout.rendered function.
I recommend to get reference of fullCalendar instance :

```
var calendar = null    
Template.packLayout.rendered = function(){
   // only once !
   calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({...});
}

Template.packLayout.helpers ({
  data:function(){
    allReqsCursor = Requests.find();

    var handle = allReqsCursor.observeChanges({
      added: function (id, user) {
        console.log("Request added");
      },
      removed: function () {
        console.log("Request removed");
      },
      changed: function() {
        console.log("Request changed");
        if(calendar){
          calendar.today();
        }

      }
    });
    return allReqsCursor;
  }
})
```

Template.packLayout.helpers.data is being rerun every time Requests collection is updated.
Something like above code should help you.

Instead using Template.packLayout.helpers.data function you can use:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
    allReqsCursor = Requests.find();
    // update calendar
})
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba, this is getting closer. The issue now is that caledar.today() is throwing Exception in queued task: TypeError: undefined is not a function, and I'm still not seeing the changes to the events until I refresh the page. The documentation seems to me to suggest that calendar.today() should work, but its not for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, the "today" event needs to be calendar.fullCalendar('today'); to get the page to render the current month when I change a request, and if the request is on a previous month I can then see the change when I navigate back, however, for requests in the current month, I get the events fired, but because the page doesn't re-render I'm still not seeing the change reflected until I manually refresh. Any ideas how to get the event to refresh?

Comment: Discovered the "rerenderEvents" function in the full calender docs but that doesn't appear to do anything (the events do log the added observer events but nothing changes on the screen).

Comment: Just discovered something even funkier. When the app is first loaded, no events on the displayed month are rendered, until you move to another month and back again. So the problem seems to be in the way blaze renders the whole calendar.

Comment: Can you create very basic meteor app which reproduces the problem and push it to github ? Then I will try to help you directly on that repo.

Comment: Basic example is at https://github.com/pnunn/testFullCalendar. This shows the problem pretty well (see readme).

Answer (score 0):

Use the internal calendar functions to re-render the calendar when things change:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if (Session.equals('calendarTemplateRendered', false) ||
        !calendarSubs.ready() ||
        typeof Calendar === 'undefined') {
        console.log('exiting because there is no objects to process');
        return;
    }

    console.log('trying to autorun');
    var entries = Calendar.find().fetch(),
       $calendar = $('#calendar');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', entries);
    $calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

Blaze does the rest for you. Dunno how efficient this is but it works pretty nicely for me.
Now you can just manipulate the subscription 'Calendar' "insert, del etc' and the calendar will work properly.